# Before and After update trigger on same table

Tags: sql-server, trigger, c#

I have a table with 4 columns `qty`, `qtydiff`, `price` and `value`.

I want a `after update trigger` that fires when qty row values change (more than one rows).

The `Before trigger` should read and store the old values from qty and After trigger should subtract old value from new value on `qty` column, get the difference value in `qtydiff` and multiply that with `price` column and update the result in the `value` column.

The code below is just a concept code that I have not tested yet, I am not sure it would work or not but is there a way to get before and after update to work in the same trigger?

```
 CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Price_Modified]
       ON [dbo].[STOCK]
       BEFORE UPDATE ON STOCK
    AS BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        IF UPDATE (Qty) 
        BEGIN
            SELECT qty
            FROM STOCK
        END 
AFTER UPDATE
    AS BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        IF UPDATE (Qty) 
        BEGIN
            UPDATE Stock
            SET value = price * qtydiff
            FROM STOCK
            WHERE qtydiff = oldvalue - newvalue
        END 
    END
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no `BEFORE` trigger in SQL Server. An `INSTEAD OF` trigger can be used to provide similar functionality but the trigger code would need to perform the `UPDATE`.

However, an `AFTER` trigger can be used here by using the `INSERTED` (new) and `DELETED` (old) virtual tables to get the values needed for the calculation. The example below assumes a primary key column named `StockID` with a value that cannot be changed.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Price_Modified]
    ON [dbo].[STOCK]
    AFTER UPDATE
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
IF UPDATE (Qty) 
BEGIN
    UPDATE s
    SET value = new.price * (new.Qty - old.Qty)
    FROM STOCK AS s
    JOIN inserted AS new ON new.StockID = s.StockID
    JOIN deleted AS old ON old.StockID = s.StockID
    WHERE new.Qty <> old.Qty;
END;

GO
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for !  Trigger on Update with a formula for valueDelta = new-old . I was looking for the Before Update and did not know deleted meant original values .. perhaps MS should have named it original rows ..or previous.

Comment: @StixO, blame Sybase rather than Microsoft for the virtual table names. These names are artifacts from the [port of Sybase SQL Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Microsoft_SQL_Server) to OS/2 and Windows Intel platforms circa 1990.

Comment: Dan Guzman - I meant to add - amazing someone else that knows what OS/2 is! :-) 
Some functionality in that OS (circa 2000)  still has windows beat , Multi-Tasking , and threading in particular!